# Hosting SyntaxHighlighter on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, blog, syntax-highlighting

My blog is a low-traffic blog and occasionally contains code. I decided to host SyntaxHighlighter myself and uploaded files to my Dropbox and configured my blog accordingly. I am able to see the code properly highlighted.

Would hosting static files on Dropbox be a trouble for my account, in terms of bandwidth?

Comment: You'll be fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We watch carefully for any fraudulent use of Dropbox public links and will suspend suspicious links when they are detected. Links that use up more than 20 GB/day for Basic (free) accounts and 200 GB/day for Pro and Teams (paid) accounts are automatically suspended.

From [Dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/45).